# Impala import data from an SQL file

Tags: hive, hdfs, impala

I have the .sql files in HDFS which has mysql INSERT queries. I created an external table in impala with the appropriate schema. Now I want to run all the insert commands stored in HDFS to the table. Is there a way to do it? Data size is 900GB!

Is any other way to import the .sql files from HDFS? We have tried with hive but it requires all the insert fields to be in lowercase which we do not have.

Comment: Question is not clear. You have asked " Is any other way to import the .sql files from HDFS?" - To where you want to import from HDFS? Also kindly provide more details about what you have tried with some examples.

Comment: Hi Surendra, We need the data (Which is in .sql format having insert statments) to be imported from HDFS to ANY hadoop environment which supports mysql-like querying (Like Hive, Hbase, Impala). Some things we tried : Using "source <hdfs location of the .sql file>" in hive and impala shell. This did not work as source command accepts only local files and not hdfs locations. I wonder if there is any other way.